# how to align elements using css in angular typeahead

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

http://plnkr.co/edit/LmMwgy2gig11nQXzCt1I?p=preview

I want the end result to look like this:
[image]

How should my css be, so that my search button is aligned with and right next to the search input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tMf9SM?p=preview)**

```
    <div class="srch">
      <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
      <button>search</button>
    </div>

    .srch button {
      float: right position: absolute;
      margin-left: -56px;
      display: table-cell;
      background: #08c;
      color: #fff;
      height: 30px;
      border: none;
    }
    .srch input {
      float: left;
      padding-right: 60px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 300px; float: left; height: 40px;"></div>
    <div style="width: 80px; float: left; height: 40px;"></div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

You then place the button inside the second div and the input in the first...

Answer (score 0):

Make the surrounding element (  ) position relative.

Make the input position absolute, then position it.

For the mag icon, simply use a background image making sure you set the display to 'block' and set the correct width and height. Remove the search text with font-size: 0;